# RSpec test failing but app working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise, capybara

Im following the Rails 4 In Action tutorial and Im up to chapter 7.

This is the error Im seeing:

```
± bundle exec rspec
.F........................

Failures:

  1) Admin::UsersController GET #index returns http success
     Failure/Error: get :index
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate!' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/admin/application_controller.rb:10:in `authorize_admin!'
     # ./spec/controllers/admin/users_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.2 seconds (files took 1.86 seconds to load)
26 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/admin/users_controller_spec.rb:6 # Admin::UsersController GET #index returns http success
```

./app/controllers/admin/application_controller.rb looks like this:

```
class Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_admin!

  def index
  end

  private

  def authorize_admin!
    authenticate_user!

    unless current_user.admin?
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "You must be an admin to do that."
    end
  end
end
```

./app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb looks like this:

```
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.order(:email)
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "User has been created."
      redirect_to admin_users_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "User has not been created."
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
    end
end
```

./spec/controllers/admin/users_controller_spec.rb looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Admin::UsersController, type: :controller do

  describe "GET #index" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end

end
```

As you can probably tell Im a little bit out of my depth, any help solving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe `authenticate_user!` comes from Warden which is part of Devise?

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup rspec to use Devise?

Try adding the following to spec/rails_helper.rb

```
# note: require 'devise' after require 'rspec/rails'
require 'devise'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  #...
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
  #...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

using RSpec, you can put the following inside a file named `spec/support/devise.rb` or in your `spec/spec_helper.rb` (or `spec/rails_helper.rb` if you are using `rspec-rails`):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :view
end
```

Just be sure that this inclusion is made after the require `rspec/rails` directive.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far guys, I have the following in spec/rails_helper.rb:

`config.include Warden::Test::Helpers, type: :feature`
`config.after(type: :feature) { Warden.test_reset! }`